# Minimum characters in WordPress editor

Tags: wordpress, editor

Is it possible to set minimum characters in WordPress editor, meaning that publishing the article is not possible until the minimum is complied?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, take the [tour], and read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Open up your `functions.php` file or wherever else you write custom `PHP` code and paste in the following:

```
function display_short_error_message($messages)
{

global $post;
$content = $post->post_content;
if (str_word_count($content) < 100 ) {
$error_message = 'Post Should be at Least 100 Words';
add_settings_error('post_short_error', '', $error_message, 'error');
settings_errors( 'post_short_error' );
$post->post_status = 'draft';
wp_update_post($post); // Place post in Draft status
return;
}

return $messages;

}

add_action('post_updated_messages', 'display_short_error_message');
```

`post_updated_messages` - This redirects to a function in which we simply extract the length of the post, and compare it to a minimum length.